# Frozen python executable fails with "ImportError: No module named site"

Tags: python, static-linking

We have a frozen executable created out of custom compiled python2.7 which is static linked to OpenSSL. We use freeze.py that comes with python to create the executable. On a machine with LDAP running, somehow the program links to system OpenSSL libraries and crashes. Works on all other machines with no issues except machines with LDAP running. The crash happens around reading of a tarfile using python tarfile module.

The executable and libraries have RPATH set to $ORIGIN.

To avoid the linking to system OpenSSL, tried compiling python with -Bsymbolic option but now the frozen executable is failing with "ImportError: No module named site". strace shows the current directory from which exe is running is not considered for lookup of .so files packaged along with executable. All .so files from python (libpython2.7* and lib-dynload) are in the same directory as executable. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to the directory to this directory. Tried by removing LINKFORSHARED="Xlinker --export-dynamic".

Any suggestions on why initial program is linking to system OpenSSL even though binaries are static linked with OpenSSL on a machine running LDAP. Also how to use -Bsymbolic with python and freeze.py?

Modified stuff from Makefile of freeze program

CONFIG_ARGS='--enable-shared' '--prefix=/pythoncompile' 'CC=gcc -m64 -march=nocona' 'CXX=g++' 'AR=ar' 'RANLIB=ranlib' 'LD=ld' 'NM=nm' 'CFLAGS=' 'CPPFLAGS=-fPIC -pthread -I/pythoncompile/openssl/include -Dlinux_x86_64 -I/pythoncompile/zlib/include' 'LDFLAGS=-lpthread  -L/pythoncompile/build -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,-rpath=$$ORIGIN -Wl,-rpath-link=. -L/pythoncompile/zlib/lib' 'LDSHARED=' 'LINKFORSHARED='

LDFLAGS=-lpthread   -L/pythoncompile -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,-rpath=$$ORIGIN -Wl,-rpath-link=. -L/pythoncompile/zlib/lib -L$(LIBDIR) -lpython2.7